# How to refresh the bubbles content via ajax rather than refreshing entire bubble?

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip, qtip2

I am using the qtip2 Jquery plug-in to provide suggestions on keyup in an input but what I would like to do is instead of refreshing the entire tool-tip bubble every time the content is updated id rather just refresh the content of the tool-tip without closing it.

So effectively if there is no tool tip present it will show the tool-tip and call the content via Ajax but if there is an existing tool-tip it will just update the content of the existing tool tip.

http://jsfiddle.net/fDavN/11723/

Ok Iv updated my code and it kinda works but I am getting an error: typeError: $(...).updateContent is not a function.

Anbody know why?

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
var title = 'KnowledgeBase Suggestions';

$('#name').on("keyup", function () {
    if($(this).data('qtip') ) {
        var getFormUrl = "http://qtip2.com/demos/data/owl";
        $.ajax({ url: getFormUrl,
            success: function (data) {

                $(this).updateContent($(".qtip-content").html(data));
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        $(this).qtip({
            content: {
                text: "Loading...",
                ajax:{
                    url: 'http://qtip2.com/demos/data/owl', // Use href attribute as URL
                    type: 'GET', // POST or GET
                    data: {}, // Data to pass along with your request
                    success: function(data, status) {
                        // Process the data
                        // Set the content manually (required!)
                        this.set('content.text', data);
                    }
                },
                title: {
                    button: true,
                    text: title
                }
            },
            position: {
                my: 'top left',
                at: 'center right',
                adjust: {
                    mouse: false,
                    scroll: false,
                    y: 5,
                    x: 25
                }
            },
            show: {
                when: false, // Don't specify a show event
                ready: true, // Show the tooltip when ready
                delay: 1500,
                effect: function() {
                    $(this).fadeTo(800, 1);
                }
            },
            hide: false,
            style: {
                classes : 'qtip-default qtip qtip qtip-tipped qtip-shadow', //qtip-rounded'
                tip: {
                    offset: 0
                }
            }
        });

    }

});
```

});

Comment: what is the updateContent function? instead of ` $(this).updateContent($(".qtip-content").html(data));` is ` $(".qtip-content").html(data);` enough?

Comment: Ok I see whats going on now. Its not finding updateContent() at all and just using $(".qtip-content").html(data). updateContent()  is an api call to a function in qtip for updating the internal content of the bubble. Looks like I dont need to user it though ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A stab in the dark as I don't know what `updateContent` does but you might have an issue with how you are referencing `$(this)`

try changing

```
$('#name').on("keyup", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.data('qtip') ) {
        var getFormUrl = "http://qtip2.com/demos/data/owl";
        $.ajax({ url: getFormUrl,
            success: function (data) {

                $this.updateContent($(".qtip-content").html(data));
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        ....
```

the reason is `this` is a different `this` when inside the ajax callback